# Combinations - separating into groups

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Could someone check to see if my proposed solution is correct or not?

---

15 students (including x, y, z) are randomly divided into 3 groups (A, B, C). Group A has 3 members, B has 4 members and C has 8.

(a) Find the total number of ways to form 3 groups;

(b) Find the probability that x, y, and z are in the same group.

(c) Find the probability that not all of them are in the same groups.

---

My answers:-

(a)The number of ways to form 3 groups $= _{15}C_3 × _{12}C_4 × _8C_8 = 225225$

(b) We treating x+y+z as one unit called t.

Case-1) - If t is in A, there is only $1$ way to form A, plus {$_{12}C_4$ to form B and  $_8C_8$ to form C} giving a total of $1 × _{12}C_4 × _8C_8 = \alpha$ , say.

Case-2) - If t is in B, there are $_{12}C_1$ ways to form B plus {$_{11}C_3$ to form A and  $_8C_8$ to form C} giving a total of $_{12}C_1 × _{11}C_3 × _8C_8 = \beta$ , say.

**After edit**

Case-3) – If t is in C, there are $_{**12**}C_5$ ways to form C plus {$_7C_3$ to form A and $_4C_4$ to form B} giving a total of $_{**12**}C_5 × _7C_3 × _4C_4 = \gamma$ , say.

Thus, the total number of ways of having them in the same group $= \alpha + \beta + \gamma = \delta$ , say.

The required probability is then $\frac {\delta}{225225}$.

(c) The total number of ways that they are not in the same group $= 225225 – \delta$.

The required probability $= \frac {225225 – \delta}{225225}$.

Comment: Looks okay to me.

Comment: Looks **not entirely** okay to me: $_{14}C_5$ should be $_{12}C_5$.

Comment: @barakmanos Nice catch. Corrected.